# android sqlite foreign key update fails

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I wonder if someone has stumbled upon strange behavior of sqlite foreign keys.

My problems occurs when I update a key variant (parcours_id) that points to another tables primary key parcours (eid) and is declared a foreign key.

The involved tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE parcours(
    eid character varying(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(50),
    comment text,
    location_id character varying(36),
    owner_id character varying(36),
    change_id integer NOT NULL,
    change_flag smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT fk_location_id FOREIGN KEY (location_id)
      REFERENCES location (eid) 
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
)



CREATE TABLE variant (
    eid character varying(36) PRIMARY KEY,
    parcours_id character varying(36) NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50),
    comment text,
    created TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    active smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    selected smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    tgt_count integer NOT NULL,
    owner_id  character varying(36) 
      DEFAULT '687baa6e-556f-43f2-897a-f1dfb371541a',
    change_id integer NOT NULL,
    change_flag smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT fk_parcours_id FOREIGN KEY (parcours_id)
    REFERENCES parcours (eid) 
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE RESTRICT 
)
```

The foreign key relationship from of variant( parcours_id ) to parcours( eid ) works perfectly on insert but fails on update with

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: foreign key mismatch: , while compiling: UPDATE variant SET parcours_id=?,name=?,comment=?,created=?,active=?,selected=?,tgt_count=?,owner_id=?,change_id=?,change_flag=? WHERE eid=?
```

Now this problem is slightly philosophical because at this point I do not need to update the key variant (parcours_id) because it has not changed. I decided to implement the update funtion only once allways updating all fields except for the primary key. Generally I do not expect the problematic value to ever change so I could just leave it out  of the update.

It looks to me like my implemention is ok, because if I disable foreign keys on the database without changing anything else it works, the foreign key is updated correctly and the integrity of the database is intact after the update.

To me this proves that the problem is not caused by my implementation but seems to be a general misunderstanding of how sqlite handles foreigng key updates.

Any suggestions ?

EDIT:
After removing the key variant( parcours_id) from the update I still get an SQLITE exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

The SQL Statement is:

```
UPDATE variant SET name=?,comment=?,created=?,active=?,selected=?,tgt_count=?,owner_id=?,change_id=?,change_flag=? WHERE eid=?
```

Answer (score 0):

> The foreign key relationship from of variant( parcours_id ) to parcours( eid ) works perfectly on insert but fails on update with

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: foreign key mismatch: , while compiling: UPDATE variant SET parcours_id=?,name=?,comment=?,created=?,active=?,selected=?,tgt_count=?,owner_id=?,change_id=?,change_flag=? WHERE eid=?
```

Given your foreign key constraint, the update *should* fail if the value you're attempting to set for `parcours_id` in your `UPDATE` statement doesn't exist in the `eid` column of any of the rows in `parcours`.  For example:

`SELECT eid FROM parcours ORDER BY eid;`

```
eid
-----
a
b
c
```

`UPDATE variant SET parcours_id = 'zzz' WHERE eid = '123';` should fail, since the value `zzz` doesn't exist in the `eid` column in `parcours`.

`UPDATE variant SET parcours_id = 'b' WHERE eid = '123';` on the other hand, should work fine, since the value `b` does exist.

I just tested this behavior using your `CREATE TABLE` statements (also creating a fake `location` table), and it works as expected.  You can compare the `parcours_id` value you were using in your `UPDATE variant` statement with the output from `SELECT eid FROM parcours ORDER BY eid;` to verify.

See [Sqlite Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_basics) for more info.

> EDIT: After removing the key variant( parcours_id) from the update I still get an SQLITE exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

This could be related to other constraints, like `NOT NULL`.  Check the parameters which you were passing in your `UPDATE` statement for any `null` values, particularly for `tgt_count` and `change_id`, since these columns don't have default values.

You could also try removing the `NOT NULL` constraints from your `CREATE TABLE variant` statement and running your update to verify whether `NOT NULL` is the constraint in question.

Comment: Maybe I did not make it clear enough but the data that I enter is not likely to be the problem. The foreign key does not actually change between inserting and later updating the object and I can see, that it works ok because the object I update is still correctly associated with the target of the foreign key after the update.  I also used debug statements to make sure that the key I update is updated with the same value.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that when you perform the update, the value you use for the foreign key in the update is the same as in the record at the time of the update?  And you are getting a runtime error with "foreign key mismatch"?  I tested this scenario (Android 5.0.1, API 21) using your `CREATE TABLE` statements, and this did not happen.  What version of Android are you running?  Also, did you resolve your second constraint error?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am seeing. I have been using an Android Virtual Device with API level 14 to test.But I agree that it sounds a weird, I will have to look over it again and check if I have overlooked something

Comment: There were some big changes in `sqlite` in Android since then -- for instance, [shell.c API 14](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sqlite/+/ics-mr0-release/dist/shell.c) vs. [shell.c API 21](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sqlite/+/android-5.0.2_r1/dist/shell.c) -- so that might explain why we were experiencing different behavior.  Perhaps try testing a later API level in the emulator?

Comment: I have extracted crucial parts of my code into a test application and there it executes OK. So it looks like the problem is somewhere in my code. I will have to add more code to the test application until it fails to find the problem. I will post my result here when I have one.

Comment: Interesting... I'll be looking forward to the results; I'm genuinely curious.